# Change TwitterButton attribute value with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I'm having issues trying to access the data-text field with my twitter button. Im trying to customize the text based on a few selections by the user. Using JQuery i try to access even the anchor's text but it always comes back undefined. I'm not sure why i can't seem to access the values in the anchor field.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#TweetCounties").change(function() {
    var seletedCounty = $('#TweetCounties :selected').text();
    var seletedValue = $('#TweetCounties').val();
    if (seletedValue !== "0") {

      //ALL undefined
      var tweet = $('.twitter-hashtag-button').data("text");
      var tweetButton = $('.twitter-hashtag-button').text();

      var tweetButtonNew = $('#twitterButton2').text();
      var tweetButtonNew1 = $('.twitterButton').text();
      var test = $('#tweetButton a');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div class="tweetButtonLaytout">
  <a id="twitterButton" class="twitter-hashtag-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=Test" data-text="#MyFirstHashTag Testing text" data-show-count="false">Tweet #Test</a>
  <select id="TweetCounties" value="0">
    <option value="0">Select Area</option>
    <option value="1">Dublin</option>
    <option value="2">Cavan</option>
    <option value="3">Wicklow</option>
    <option value="4">Galway</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: because that anchor tag is an iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and reload hashtag button using Twitter Lib API, because it's overwrite `a` element with `iframe` to button, so you can't change it without using their api (`iframe` is out of `jQuery` range).

**Solution:**

It's create first button after select from `#TweetCounties` and store it as `currentButton`, when `#TweetCounties` change it's create new button, remove old one and overwrite `currentButton` with new one.

This way is better then reload js when `#TweetCounties` change value because we have loaded twitter lib one time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentButton;
  $("#TweetCounties").change(function() {
    var seletedCounty = $('#TweetCounties :selected').text();
    var seletedValue = $('#TweetCounties').find(":selected").attr('value');
    if (seletedValue !== "0") {
        var btnContainer = $('#buttonContainer');
        twttr.widgets.createHashtagButton(seletedCounty,
          document.getElementById('buttonContainer'))
          .then(function(newButton) {
            $(currentButton).remove();
            currentButton = newButton;
           });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div class="tweetButtonLaytout">
  <div id="buttonContainer"></div>
   <select id="TweetCounties" value="0">
    <option value="0">Select Area</option>
    <option value="1">Dublin</option>
    <option value="2">Cavan</option>
    <option value="3">Wicklow</option>
    <option value="4">Galway</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you put the button on the page, the library of twitter creates an iframe and creates the button inside it so you mustn't modify any object inside an iframe, instead you can delete and recreate the button as you wish like this (also reloading widget js lib):

```js
function load_js()
   {
      var src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
     
      var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var script= document.createElement('script');
     
      script.type= 'text/javascript';
      script.src= src;
      script.charset= "utf-8";
     
      head.appendChild(script);
   }
   

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#TweetCounties").change(function() {
    var seletedCounty = $('#TweetCounties :selected').text();
    console.log(seletedCounty);
    var seletedValue = $('#TweetCounties').val();
    if (seletedValue !== "0") {

      //
      $("iframe[id^='twitter-widget-']").remove();
      $(".tweetButtonLaytout").prepend('<a id="twitterButton" class="twitter-hashtag-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=' + seletedCounty + '" data-text="#MyFirstHashTag Testing text" data-show-count="false">Tweet #' + seletedCounty + '</a>');
      load_js();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<div class="tweetButtonLaytout">
  <a id="twitterButton" class="twitter-hashtag-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=Test" data-text="#MyFirstHashTag Testing text" data-show-count="false">Tweet #Test</a>
  <select id="TweetCounties" value="0">
    <option value="0">Select Area</option>
    <option value="1">Dublin</option>
    <option value="2">Cavan</option>
    <option value="3">Wicklow</option>
    <option value="4">Galway</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** Or you can use Twitter's library as it is explained [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/hashtag-button):

```
twttr.widgets.createHashtagButton(
  "TwitterStories",
  document.getElementById("container"),
  {
    size:"large"
  }
);
```

Comment: I think it's better to use twitter api: https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/hashtag-button

Comment: That's an option too

Comment: Btw. `seletedValue` will be always `undefinied`.

Comment: Debugged it and it got value, sorry

Comment: Yeah, but it isn't supported with all browsers in this way. Better to use `el.find(":selected").attr('value')`

Comment: That's up to the question owner, sorry

Comment: You gotta concentrate on the question, cross browser issue depends on the project properties, I mean this project may only be using Chrome etc...